# Thunderbird doesn't run on Raspbian Stretch

Tags: raspbian-stretch

I have a fresh installation of Raspbian Stretch. I have successfully installed Thunderbird (Icedove) mail client, but when I launch it from application menu it does nothing.

Comment: Does starting it from a terminal work?

Comment: I started it from application menu. I tryed it from terminal too. After several second it finished by “ incorrect instruction.

Comment: I started it from application menu. I tryed it from terminal too. After several second it finished by “ ILLEGAL instruction".

Comment: Strange. I've just installed thunderbird on my pi and it works without problems. I installed it from the terminal: `sudo apt-get install icedove`. Perhaps you need to do a `sudo apt-get update` to fetch the last package? Can you post the output of `apt show icedove` ?

Comment: Thank for your notice, that it is strange. It led me to decision to do a complete new installation of Raspbian Stretch and Thunderbird. After all necessary settings and apt-get upgrade it works !